# Sending iterator of ng-repeat as an argument to a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have below code in which I am trying to iterate through the array using ng-repeat and sending the iterator as an argument to a function.

a) Creating an array stepTitle.

b) Iterating through steptitle using ng-repeat.Iterator is 'temp'

c) Sending temp as an argument to a function getTitle.

Problem-- How to send an argument to this function inside ng-repeat tag.
the call stepTitle(temp) does not work.
Code snippet:

```
Directive.displaySteps = ['baseClass',
    function(compBase) {
      return {
            controller: function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
                                        $scope.steptitle =["Step1", "Step2", "Step3"];                 
                                    },
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            template: function(elem,$attrs) {
                return('<div>'+
                '<ul class="nav" ng-repeat="temp in steptitle">'+
                            '<li >'+
                                '<a class="active" id="anchor" href="javascript:void">'+
                                    '<span class="ps-icn-single-start" id="step1_span"/>'+
                                    '<span>{{'+ getTitle(temp)+'}}</span>'+
                                    //'<span>{{temp}}</span>'+
                                '</a>'+ 
                            '</li>'+
                    '</ul>'+
                '</div>');  
    }
```

Comment: You are calling the `getTitle()` function while contructing your template. The variable `temp` is undefined. You might want: `'<span>{{ getTitle(temp) }}</span>'`.

Comment: You include the expression into the string, because it will get compiled by angular. the expression is NOT JavaScript, it is uncompiled expression. Angular needs to convert that into JavaScript and execute it against the controller.

Comment: see working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0IOfdEDMSGBmpNolpkvJ?p=preview)

Comment: @CallumLinington  In my code, the function gettitle is not part of $scope namespace which caused this issue. Whenever I write '<span>{{<myObject>.gettitle{{temp}}}}</span>'  I get an error "temp undefined". However now I have kept one temporary function in my $scope and from this function I am calling <namespace>.gettitle. It is working now. Thanks for sharing the code snippet at plnkr it really helped. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function during the template creation which you shouldn't, instead it should be compiled and then called. So change your code to this:

```
Directive.displaySteps = ['baseClass',
  function(compBase) {
    return {
        controller: function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
                                    $scope.steptitle =["Step1", "Step2", "Step3"];                 
                                },
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: function(elem,$attrs) {
            return('<div>'+
            '<ul class="nav" ng-repeat="temp in steptitle">'+
                        '<li >'+
                            '<a class="active" id="anchor" href="javascript:void">'+
                                '<span class="ps-icn-single-start" id="step1_span"/>'+
                                '<span>{{getTitle(temp)}}</span>'+
                                //'<span>{{temp}}</span>'+
                            '</a>'+ 
                        '</li>'+
                '</ul>'+
            '</div>');  
}
```

Comment: '<span>{{getTitle(temp)}}</span>'  This piece of code inside the template will be treated as a string. angular doesnot treat getTitle as a function name that is to be resolved at runtime. Correct thing would be to exclude getTitle from being put inside single quote. question still remains how to pass temp as a variable.